# $|G|= 2^n, o(g)=2~\forall g \in G, g \neq e$ show that G is abelian

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Question as in title:  I have attempted this question by saying that the homomorpism that maps G to $Z_2$ is onto, $Z_2$ is abelian so G must be abelian.

Comment: This question has been asked multiple times on this site (so go and look for the answer) and you do not have to assume that $|G|$ is a power of $2$.

Comment: Apologies I will remove the question

Comment: Removing the question is not necessary. Just next time take a closer look on this site.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We have, for all $a,b\in G$,
$$abba=e=baba$$
Hence $ab=ba$